# How to replace single quote within a string with two single quotes in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the below data in my text file.

```
1|"John"|3,5400
2|"Jim"|7,7300
3|"Smith,Robin",3,4300
4|"O'Brien",10,8200
```

and I want this output:

```
(1,'John',3,5400)
(2,'Jim',7,7300)
(3,'Smith,Robin',3,4300)
(4,'O''Brien',10,8200)
```

Basically I want to replace `|` character with commas and double quotes with single quote. I am able to achieve that with this piece of code:

```
String text2 = textAfterHeader.replaceAll("\\|", ",").replaceAll("\"", "'").replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]'[a-zA-Z]", "''");
```

output that I am getting:

```
1,'John',3,5400
2,'Jim',7,7300
3,'Smith,Robin',3,4300
4,'''rien',10,8200
```

But I have one more requirement where I need to put two single quotes whenever a single quote appears between a string, for example, O'Brien as O''Brien. But this part is not working.

Comment: Why not do the replacement of double and single quotes the other way around: `.replace("'", "''").replace("\"", "'")`?

Comment: And then, replace blanks with `) (`. Lastly, prefix the string with `(` and suffix it with `)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks a lot ..!! It worked..!! Appreciate your help here..!!

Answer (score 3):

As was suggested by @AndyTurner, you can simplify the problem by first replacing all `'` with `''` and then replace all `"` with `'`. The only thing missing after that are the parenthesis, which can be added in two steps:

1. Replace all blanks with `) (` (notice the blank between the parenthesis).
2. Add a leading `(` and a trailing `)` to the `String`.

All together, a solution could look like this:

```
final String output = "(" 
        + input
            .replace("'", "''")
            .replace("\"", "'")
            .replace("|", ",")
            .replace(" ", ") (")
        + ")";
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/NHTJbt)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be:

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String output = new StringBuilder("(").append(
        input.replaceAll("\\|", ",")
        .replaceAll("'", "''") // (*)
        .replaceAll("\"", "'") // (**)
        .replaceAll(lineSeparator, ")" + lineSeparator + "("))
        .append(")").toString();
```

Note the replacement (*) must come before (**). Since you need to replace exact characters instead of variable regular expressions, you want better use `replace` instead of `replaceAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

\s*\'\s*

and a call to Replace with " will do the job.